# How ॐ (OM) is written in Brahmi Script?

Tags: sanskrit, om

Sanskrit is said to be originated from "Drums of Lord Shiva". There's a [famous story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiva_Sutras#Traditional_story_of_origin) of Panini composing grammar of Sanskrit from sounds (Maheswara Sutras) of lord Shiva's Damaru.

> Panini was a student at a Gurukula (a system of education in the 4th
>   century BC). He was a dull student, and was often teased by many of
>   his friends. So, worried about his situation, the Gurumata (the wife
>   of the Guru) advised him to go to the Himalayas to do tapas. So he
>   went to the Himalayas and started meditating on Lord Shiva. Lord
>   Shiva, pleased with Panini's strong tapas, came and danced before him
>   . While dancing, the sound from his Damaru (the small drum like
>   musical instrument that Shiva plays) was heard by Panini as the
>   Maheshwara Sutrani. Thus, Panini wrote the Maheshwara Sutras and
>   formed the Sanskrit grammar.

Sanskrit was composed initially in [Brahmi](http://www.ancientscripts.com/brahmi.html) Script and later Devanagari Script was used. Sanskrit is also believed to have no script.

We all know, Sacred syllable OM, the Pranava, the Sabdha Brahman, is written as ॐ in Devanagari Script or lipi. But how is "OM" or "AUM" or ॐ written in Brahmi Script? This Image says how ॐ  was developed.

[image]

As "O" is written as [image] in Brahmi as mentioned in above link, Is ॐ written as [image] or something else ?

Comment: [This](http://www.ancientscripts.com/brahmi.html) website here gives letter of Brahmi script.. After seeing writing style of Kam Gam... I also think one dot is placed at side of O...

Comment: When was Panini born...?

Comment: @Tezz  But my doubt is why OM as Brahmi script is not popular like Devanagari ॐ. Also, i doubt whether Brahmi was precursor to Devanagari. If Devanagari follows Brahmi, how [ॐ Parvat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Om_Parvat) can exist before invention of Devanagari script?

Comment: @Tezz Wiki says he lived during 4th century BC. May be rewrote Sanskrit grammar with help of Shiva.

Comment: Om may be same in both Brahmi and Devnagari... People often identify shape of Om with shape of Lord Ganesha...

Comment: @Tezz could be. I have seen some images of Ganesha as OM.

Comment: Furthermore we can't tell which is earlier as events may repeat cyclically in chaturyugas and kalpas...

Comment: @Tezz Well, Patanjali is mentioned by Chitraketu, the previous birth of Vritrasura, in the Srimad Bhagavatam: http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/6/15/12-15 And Patanjali is the author of the Mahabhashya, the standard commentary on Panini's Ashtadhyayi.  So Panini is quite ancient.  But in any case as far as I know neither Panini nor Patanjali make any reference to written scripts.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Devanagari script was a relatively recent development, and the reverence of the written Om symbol is even more recent than that, not something mentioned in scripture.  I think the Om Parvat may just be a coincidence, or perhaps the gods placed it there knowing that one day that would be how humans will write Om.

Comment: @Tezz The association of the Om symbol with Ganesha is a really recent development, perhaps within the last hundred years or less.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Why would Devas allude at something that was going to happen in near future? I also don't think it as just coincidence. May be i should ask this as separate question.

Comment: You may check this https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:O3M-brahmi.png

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani Wow. Good find. You can post it as answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ॐ (OM)(ओ३म्) can be [written in Brahmi](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:O3M-brahmi.png) script as:

[image: OM in Brahmi]

Further, there is book [Brahmi-Rediscovering the lost script](http://www.mrane.com/images/bramhi.pdf) written by Ankita Roy. This book contains many information about Brahmi script (Lipi). Below is the image how ॐ described in the book.

[image]

Comment: Please correct OM is written in TULU script not hindi Tulu script was used to write sanskrit mantras