# Is Brahmi Script older than Devanagari Script? If yes, how this can be reconciled with ॐ Parvat?

Tags: history, sanskrit, om

Sanskrit Language is believed to have no written native script. [History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmic_scripts#History) says Brahmi Script was used for Sanskrit Language during the reign of legendary Emperor Ashoka which was around 3rd century BC. But there are some claims that Brahmi script was even used before period of Ashoka.

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari) says Nagari Script was developed from Brahmi scripts and Nagari Script is very similar to Devanagari. But Brahmi Script appears very different from Nagari script. See [this page](http://www.ancientscripts.com/brahmi.html) and [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C4%81gar%C4%AB_script) and compare the scripts.

And [ॐ (OM) Parvat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Om_Parvat) is a mountain in Himalayas which is situated partially in India and Nepal. Snow clad OM parvat looks like *Shabhda Brahman* ॐ.

[image]

Image Credits: [Wikimedia Commons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Om_Parvat#/media/File:Om_Parvat.JPG)

OM symbol is generally written as ॐ in Devanagari. OM in OM Parvat is similar to "OM" of Nagari Script and Devanagari Script. Himalayas were formed [50 million years ago](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-3067960/Mystery-Indias-movement-revealed-Scientists-discover-continent-sped-Eurasia-huge-impact-created-Himalayas-80-million-years-ago.html) and so was the OM Parvat. Even according to Mythology, Himavat, personification of Himalayas and father of Parvati and Ganga was born at the beginning of Vaivasvara Manvantara as he was present during the marriage of Shiva and Parvati. So, OM Parvat was an ancient one.

So, Is Brahmi Script older than Devanagari Script? If yes, how this can be reconciled with OM Parvat? Is OM symbol same for all Scripts, which I think not correct? I asked a question how OM is represented in Brahmi Script [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11640/3500).

Comment: Like I said, I think there are two possible explanations: either the Om Parvat thing is a coincidence, or it was something set up by the gods long ago knowing one day humans would write Om in that way.  In any case, I don't know of any scriptures that say that Om is written on a mountain in the Himalayas.  For that matter I don't know of any scriptures that discuss the written Om symbol.

Comment: But yeah, Brahmi script is older than Devanagari script.  And the divine lanaguage of Sanskrit is older than Brahmi, Devanagari, or any other script.  Sanskrit has no native script; it's a collection of sounds which has been given various scripts by human beings.

Comment: Note that this is a 3D image projected onto 2D and an interpretation is made. Depending on the location of the observer, this may not look like the pranava, and again there can be other mountains that show the pranava depending on the observer’s location.

Answer (score 2):

But this view of Brahmi script older than Sanskrit (Devanagari) appears WRONG  because it is an accepted view that VEDAS were codified by VEDAVYASA who lived in PURANIC times believed to be 7500 years to 5500 years back. The prayer by Vedavyasa to PEN them down to GANAPATHI and who oblized the same being believed to be true , then SANSKRIT in which VEDAS are available today seems to have been WRITTEN before 2800 years back, the times of BRAHMI lipi formation and that SANSKRIT LIPI is not a derivative lipi from Brahmi.

Comment: Yes, we don't need Marxist history, but present day materialistic historians don't use religious scriptures to write history.

Comment: Sanskrit is not a lipi or script. It is a language. A language can be written in any script. Devanagari and Sanskrit are totally different. Without knowing this, you have written an answer?