# What are the 10 doors of the Dharma?

Tags: mahabharata, dharma

When I read [Adi Parva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs01060.htm) about the families of the gods and how they were classified, I read that when Brahma gave ten wives to the Dharma, they were "the ten doors of the Dharma":

> 13 नामतॊ धर्मपत्न्यस ताः कीर्त्यमाना निबॊध मे
>    कीर्तिर लक्ष्मीर धृतिर मेधा पुष्टिः शरद्धा करिया तथा
>
> 14 बुद्धिर लज्जा मतिश चैव पत्न्यॊ धर्मस्य ता दश
>    **दवाराण्य** एतानि धर्मस्य विहितानि सवयं भुवा

IAST Transliteration:

> 13 nāmato dharmapatnyas tāḥ kīrtyamānā nibodha me
>   kīrtir lakṣmīr dhṛtir medhā puṣṭiḥ śraddhā kriyā tathā
>
> 14 buddhir lajjā matiś caiva patnyo dharmasya tā daśa
>   dvārāṇy etāni dharmasya vihitāni svayaṃ bhuvā

English translation (by K. M. Ganguli):

> Listen
>   as I recount the wives of Dharma according to their names. They are ten in all--Kirti, Lakshmi, Dhriti, Medha, Pushti, Sraddha, Kria, Buddhi, Lajja, and Mali. These are the wives of Dharma as appointed by the Self-create.

Translation to English by Bibek Debroy:

> Listen to me as I recite the names of Dharma’s wives—Kirti, Lakshmi, Dhriti,
>   Medha, Pushti, Shraddha, Kriya, Buddhi, Lajja and Mati. As decreed by the one who created
>   himself,20 these ten wives of Dharma are the doors to Dharma.

So my question is, what are the ten doors of the Dharma and its symbolism?

Comment: [This chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01067.htm) doesn't say so...what chapter you are referring to?

Comment: BORI mentions that Dharma wives are the doors of the Dharma

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Is original Sanskrit shloka not allowed on the site???

Comment: @YDS Yes. https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/61/5212 , https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/60/5212 and https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/126/5212 . Why are you giving more importance to only Devanagari here? and how many engaged in edit wars like you when IAST transliteration is added? Let's not be partial towards a script which can only be read  by few people. Every one should understand what is written in the answer. You haven't added what is written in the question or what is the meaning of the added verses. So, don't rollback adding only verses in Devanagari.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma You could have added IAST without removing Sanskrit.

Comment: @Pandya Where did I remove Sanskrit? Can you point out? I removed _Devanagari_ which is similar to Hindi which is not read by many. Don't equate Devanagari script with Sanskrit Language. YDS could have left it out because Devanagari is not understood by many. When there is no translation, the preference goes to transliteration not a language which is understood by some. Why Devanagari is given more importance? If I may ask. Moreover, the tag Dharma we use is for Virtue not Lord Dharma.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma IAST is one of the **Devanagari Transliteration** schemes that means the source is Sanskrit (Devanavari script).

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Devngari script is used for Hindi also that doesn't mean It's not used for Sanskrit or introduced for Sanskrit after Hindi! Sanskrit (Devanagari script) is the oldest one in which we do have Shastras in original form. Chek out [this source](http://vedicreserve.mum.edu/) which provides Shastras in Original Sanskrit.

Comment: @Pandya Heh, IAST is not Devanagari transliteration. It is Sanskrit transliteration. It's IAST and not IADT. No, Devanagari is not same as Sanskrit.  Devanagari is not the oldest script either.There are many older scripts than Devanagari. Heard of Brahmi script? Script is only a form to write a language. It can be written in any script. Vedic reserve site may or may not give books in original Sanskrit but DN we write now has changed a lot since centuries & not original. If the oldest is given preference on this site, shall we start writing and talking Sanskrit after learning it. Why English?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Visit [Devanagari Transliteration schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari_transliteration#IAST) where you'll find IAST. Yes, I heard about Brahmi script but we don't have Shastras surviving in that form. The oldest surviving script we have for Original Shastras is Devanagari Sanskrit. It may be possible that many doesn't understand Devanagari Sanskrit, however many understand it. e.g. The symbol of our site is in Devanagari, not in [Brahmi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11640/277). Will continue further discussion in chat room...

Comment: @Pandya I think you know that comments are not for extended discussion and I already pinged you on chat. Check your inbox. You didn't answer my question why we are using English when Hindu scripture are written in Sanskrit? Isn't it for understanding for all irrespective of language? " It may be possible that many doesn't understand Devanagari Sanskrit, however many understand it." what are you trying to say? Understanding matters. If a major paragraph which is crucial to answer the question is limited to only some people, then what is the meaning of being an international site.

Comment: @Pandya This is an English-language site so the less Devanagari and other Indian scripts the better. When there is an issue of space, Sanskrit-to-English transliteration should take precedence. It's because this is an English-language site. Users here may love using Devanagari but the English-speaking community cares more about English alphabet and translation. This question did not need the Sanskrit verses, neither Devanagari nor IAST. English translation would have sufficed. So you should probably delete both first and second blockquotes.

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? Therevare meanings of each of these ten and also of dharma

Answer (score 1):

The symbolism is that one who upholds these things is symbolically married to them. As for what they are, their meaning lies in how the ten are translated or what they translate to:

1. Kirti - glory or splendour
2. Lakshmi - fortune, prosperity, success
3. Dhriti - firmness, maintaining support (the root of Dhriti is the same
   as Dharma,'dhṛ' - "to uphold")
4. Medha  - intelligence or wisdom
5. Pushti  - wealth, thriving, enrichment
6. Shraddha - faith or belief, pertaining to the truth
7. Kriya - desireless action, non-attached action
8. Buddhi - intellect or discernment
9. Lajja - modesty, humbleness
10. Mali - determination, conviction, devotion

In the context of the verse, it just means these things are characteristic of Dharma and the absence of these things is the absence of Dharma.

> **1.60.13-14. Listen as I recount the wives of Dharma according to their names. They are ten in all: Kirti, Lakshmi, Dhriti, Medha, Pushti, Shraddha, Kriya, Buddhi, Lajja and Mali. These are the wives of Dharma as appointed by the Self-create.**

The symbolism of wives lies in, itself, the word translated as wife - *patnī*. *Patnī* is the feminine version of *pati*, which means husband but it also means "lord" or "master" - as in, Brihaspati, Pashupati, Vachaspati, etc. In this context, it does not refer to the ordinary meaning of wife or marriage but union. The wives are the activating, enabling forces or Shakti of Dharma. Marriage to them enables the practise and upholding of Dharma. They enable the actualisation of Dharma, its fulfilment. This is no different to the union of Purusha and Prakriti or the inactive masculine and active feminine aspects of Brahma. The ten wives make Dharma possible; without them, it is not upheld.